# Page view count not able to get session value while close the browser or browser tab

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My requirement, I want to **update** the **MYSQL** table every **30 seconds**. So I am using **PHP sessions** to store the visitor count . After 30 seconds , I will update session value to the table. It is working fine but while one time open and close the browser tab I can't get that session value.

For example if visitors open the page **one time** and close so session value is **1** , this value I can't able get and update in my table. So can you please help me.

**Here is my code :**

```
    // add custom post content
function wp_post_view_blog_visit_count($content) {

  $ip_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $post_id = get_the_ID();

  if(isset($_SESSION['wp_blog_views_two'.$post_id.$ip_addr])) {
      $_SESSION['wp_blog_views_two'.$post_id.$ip_addr] = ++$_SESSION['wp_blog_views_two'.$post_id.$ip_addr];
  }else{
      $_SESSION['wp_blog_views_two'.$post_id.$ip_addr] = 1;
  }

  $blog_view_count = $_SESSION['wp_blog_views_two'.$post_id.$ip_addr];
  echo $blog_view_count.' SESSION VALUE'.'<br>';

  $count_key = 'post_views_count_'.$post_id.$ip_addr;
  //WordPress has a function to get custom field values, get_post_meta().It accepts three parameters
  $count = (int) get_post_meta($post_id, $count_key, true);
  echo $count.' FROM TABLE'.'<br>';
  if($count == '' || $count == 0){
      //the function to delete custom fields values is delete_post_meta()
      delete_post_meta($post_id,$count_key); //delete the post meta table record
      //Saving a custom field value in the database is as easy as getting it. The function to use is add_post_meta().
      add_post_meta($post_id, $count_key, 1);//add the post meta table record
      return $content .= $count.' Views'.'<br><br>';
  }else{
      /*
      * Check the cookie is exist or not.
      * If not the set cookie for some time interval and
      * increase the count
      */      
      ++$count;
 
      if(isset($_SESSION["user".$post_id.$ip_addr])){
          if(time()-$_SESSION["login_time_stamp".$post_id.$ip_addr] > 30){ //30 seconds
            unset($_SESSION['user'.$post_id.$ip_addr]);
            unset($_SESSION["login_time_stamp".$post_id.$ip_addr]);
            unset($_SESSION['wp_blog_views_two'.$post_id.$ip_addr]);
                //To update the value of an existing custom field use the function update_post_meta() 
            update_post_meta($post_id, $count_key, $count+$blog_view_count);//update the post meta mysql table
          }
      }else{
          $_SESSION["user".$post_id.$ip_addr] = 'VIEWING'.$post_id.$ip_addr;
          $_SESSION["login_time_stamp".$post_id.$ip_addr] = time();
      }
     
  }
  return $content .= '<b style="color:red;">'.$count.'</b> Views'.'<br><br>';
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wp_post_view_blog_visit_count');
```